# How can I remove wax spilled on a painted wall?

Tags: repair, drywall, walls, stain

There was an accident where a non-extinguished candle spilled wax on a drywall. I removed most of it gently with a blunt knife, but there is a big stain left from the candlewax. Since this is an apartment on rent, is there a solution to my problem where I won't have to pay an insane amount of money to my landlord for a repaint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my solution to the problem for future reference:

First, I scraped as much of the wax as possible without damaging the drywall. I was left with a pretty bad oily stain that stood out on the white plaster. I used some dishwasher soap to remove as much of the oiliness but the porous surface has absorbed most of it already.
So, I got a repair paint pen (I used the Baufan one, there's many brands available) and it worked perfectly! It required 3-4 applications but it blended seamlessly, and while wet I used a makeup sponge to achieve the texture of the drywall.

Answer (score 1):

Generally spilled wax can be wicked up with a brown paper bag or newspaper and a clothing iron or hair dryer. If it is on a painted surface, I would try that or even hot water. If it is on an unpainted surface, then it will need to be wicked up as much as possible and then repaired.

Comment: +1 Wet paper bag and iron - you may have to do some touch up, as the heat may discolor the paint slightly - but the wax will be drawn towards the heat of the iron, as it melts.